# JPA enumerated types mapping. Best approach

Tags: java, jpa, enums, hibernate-mapping

As usual Java enum types have corresponding codes and name description.
And Java classes that contain such fields, contain them as Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    SOMEINSTANCE(1, "test1"),
    SOMEINSTANCE(2, "test2");

    private final int code;
    private final String name;
    private MyEnum(int code, String name){
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
    ... helper getter for code and name
}

@Entity
puclic class EnumHolder{
    private MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

I'm a newbie to JPA, but I wish to have the '`myEnums`' table, looked like:

```
code int not null, name varchar(50) not null)
```

And in my `enumHolder` table I want to have the `myEnumCode` field that points to the myEnums table.

Using currenlty supported both EnumType.ORDINAL and EnumType.STRING I suppose not a good idea.

And another question. How can I fill in the `myEnums` table using Java `MyEnum` class data? How would you do it? The best approach please.

**PS: here are solutions I can offer:**

Let's suppose there is table `myEnum` with `code` and name `fields`. Java `MyEnum` enum, that is described in the question. `enumHolder` table need to have `myEnumCode` reference to `myEnum.code` field. Please comment the solution if you disagree.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class EnumHolder {
    @Id private int id;
    @Transient private MyEnum myEnum;
    …
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public MyEnum getMyEnum() { return MyEnum; }
    public void setMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum) { this.myEnum = myEnum; }

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) @Column(name="myEnumCode")
    protected int getMyEnumForDb() {
        return myEnum.getCode();
    }

    protected void setMyEnumForDb(int enumCode) {
        myEnum = MyEnum.getByCode( enumCode);
    }
…
}
```

Of course there are drawbacks here. But at the moment I cannot see the better approach. Alternatives with EnumType.ORDINAL and EnumType.STRING please don't offer. I don't want to write here all problems that can exist with its usage (in Effective Java it is described concerning ordinals usage). Using EnumType.STRING I don't like either cause it does not  allow to have discription in database and request it from db.

Concerning fillind database. I think it's not difficult to write a script, that clears the `myEnum` table and then for each Java enum istance makes insert into the table. And always do it during a deployment phase.

Comment: What's the point in storing in the database values that are already hard-coded in the enum itself? The data in the database won't be used by the application anyway, and you'll eventualy have inconsistencies between the values in database and the values hard-coded in the enums.

Comment: I may need sql query that generates some reports, so storing values and its descriptions in db is very convenient for such purpose. Accessing enums in Java code also has its benefits, comparing with ordinal classes.

Answer (score 52):

The best approach would be to map a unique ID to each enum type, thus avoiding the pitfalls of ORDINAL and STRING. See this [post](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2013/09/mapping-enums-with-fixed-id-in-jpa.html) which outlines 5 ways you can map an enum.

Taken from the link above:

**1&2. Using @Enumerated**

There are currently 2 ways you can map enums within your JPA entities using the @Enumerated annotation. Unfortunately both EnumType.STRING and EnumType.ORDINAL have their limitations.

If you use EnumType.String then renaming one of your enum types will cause your enum value to be out of sync with the values saved in the database. If you use EnumType.ORDINAL then deleting or reordering the types within your enum will cause the values saved in the database to map to the wrong enums types.

Both of these options are fragile. If the enum is modified without performing a database migration, you could jeopodise the integrity of your data.

**3. Lifecycle Callbacks**

A possible solution would to use the JPA lifecycle call back annotations, @PrePersist and @PostLoad. This feels quite ugly as you will now have two variables in your entity. One mapping the value stored in the database, and the other, the actual enum.

**4. Mapping unique ID to each enum type**

The preferred solution is to map your enum to a fixed value, or ID, defined within the enum. Mapping to predefined, fixed value makes your code more robust. Any modification to the order of the enums types, or the refactoring of the names, will not cause any adverse effects.

**5. Using Java EE7 @Convert**

If you are using JPA 2.1 you have the option to use the new @Convert annotation. This requires the creation of a converter class, annotated with @Converter, inside which you would define what values are saved into the database for each enum type. Within your entity you would then annotate your enum with @Convert.

**My preference: (Number 4)**

The reason why I prefer to define my ID's within the enum as oppose to using a converter, is good encapsulation. Only the enum type should know of its ID, and only the entity should know about how it maps the enum to the database.

See the original [post](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2013/09/mapping-enums-with-fixed-id-in-jpa.html) for the code example.

Comment: Another [opinion](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html) on the best approach endorses the JPA 2.1 AttributeConverter method (#5 above).

Comment: option 4 is now my default.
so simple.
Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can add an enumerated field to your entity by using [`@Enumerated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html).  The kicker here is that you want to have your cake and eat it too - for consistency's sake, it'd be better to choose either `EnumType.ORDINAL` or `EnumType.STRING`.

Both have their pluses and minuses, which are listed [at this site](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/).  The big difference appears to be with ordering - if you have `EnumType.ORDINAL` set, you would run into problems when updating your enum.

I would encourage you to rethink the way you want to design your table.  The string and the integer essentially store the same information - what the enumerated value *is* - and you can get that back from the database without too much fuss.  It'd be better to have an `id` as a primary key on the table, then have your enumerated type either as string or ordinal value, taking into account the caveats from the link above.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Column(name = "MY_TYPE")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MyType type;

enum MyType {
type_1
type_2
}
```

then create you column like following:

```
TYPE_ID  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TYPE_1' CHECK (TYPE_ID IN ('TYPE_1', 'TYPE_2')))
```

this solved my issue.